# Lookup Field Object

Tags: lookup, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

I have to get the object name of the lookup field in any object.
I am using:

```
sobjectType objectType=Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('SA_S3_File__c').
```

then, to get the lookup field name, i am using

```
"fieldsMap.get(field).getDescribe().getType()+''=='REFERENCE'"
```

after getting the fieldname of lookup, how can i get the object name of those lookup fields?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = fieldsMap.get(field).getDescribe();   
System.debug(f.getRelationshipName())    
for(Schema.SObjectType reference : f.getReferenceTo())
{
    System.debug(reference.getDescribe().getName());
}
```

See docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Phil Hawthorn's answer but with a loop and you can just "toString" an SObjectType to get its name, no need for another describe:

```
SObjectType t = ...;

DescribeSObjectResult dt = t.getDescribe();
for (SObjectField f : dt.fields.getMap().values()) {
    DescribeFieldResult df = f.getDescribe();
    if (df.getType() == DisplayType.Reference) {
        for (SObjectType r : df.getReferenceTo()) {
            System.debug('field ' + df.getName() + ' references type ' + r);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally the `getReferenceTo` only returns one type.